# getJSON returns null MVC3 - 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, getjson

So, I am having issues with getting json from my action and was hoping someone could point out my error.

So, here is my jQuery:

```
$("#ProductSelect").change(function () {
    $.getJSON('Admin/GetProduct?id=' + $(this).val(), function (data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(json);
    });
});
```

Here is the Action it calls:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = new Product();
        product.GetProductById(id);
        return this.Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The alert in the JS keeps showing null.  There are no JS errors (used Firebug).  Using a break-point on the Action, I can see that Product is properly populated.  Any ideas?

Comment: what does your json look like? copy/paste the sample ...

Comment: That was the issue.  I was following this example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx and I was under the impression that this.Json() created the JSON for you.  So, I just made a ToJSON() method in Product and it works now.  Thanks, Xander.

Answer (score 0):

obviously your controller uses a just initialized object without any information. Do you forget to use a database object and then find that id as primary key? like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        //private DataContext db
        return Json(db.GetProductById(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```